# TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined store dispatch vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a vue component that makes use of the store Vuex. However I get a

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
```

error. I don't understand why. This is my code:

In main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router';
 import "./assets/css/tailwind.css";
import '@/assets/css/tailwind.css';
import store from './store';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

 Vue.use(Vuex);

 
new Vue({
    router, store,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

In store/indes.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

 
Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
    },
    state:  {
        token: ''
    }
})
```

In GenericForm.vue:

```
  methods:  {
    execute()  {
      console.log("GenericForm.vue")

      if (this.inputFunction)  {
        this.inputFunction()
      }

      this.register()
    },

      register () {
      console.log("register()")
      try {
        const response =   AuthenticationService.register({
          email: 'testss',
          password: 'frgr'
        })
           this.$store.dispatch('setToken', response.data.token)
           this.$store.dispatch('setUser', response.data.user)
           this.$store.router.push({
          name: 'songs'
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
/*
        this.error = error.response.data.error
*/
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

the error occurs on this line of code:

```
 this.$store.dispatch
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

AuthenticationService.js

```
import api from './api'

export default  {
    register (credentials)  {
        return api().post('register', credentials)
    }
}
```

api.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default()  =>  {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:8081'
    })
};
```

After adding `console.log`:
[image]

**EDIT2**:

New method:

```
    register: async () => {

     
      console.log("register()")
      const response = AuthenticationService.register({
        email: 'testss',
        password: 'frgr'
      }).then((response) => {

        console.log(response)
       /* this.$store.dispatch('setToken', response.data.token)
        this.$store.dispatch('setUser', response.data.user)*/
        this.$store.router.push({
          name: '/test'
        })
      });
    }
```

I get the error on

```
 this.$store.router.push({
          name: '/test'
        })
```

line:

[image]

The response gets logged alright, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are **two** problems:

**First problem**:

This code:

```js
register(credentials)  {
    return api().post('register', credentials)
}
```

is returning a `Promise`, which has no `data` property. What you want is to access the axios `response` wrapped in that promise, so you either:

- call `then` on the promise

```js
AuthenticationService.register({...}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data.token) // 'foo'
});
```

- use `async/await` inside the Vue component

**Second problem**

The problem that causes the store to be undefined, is the use of the arrow functions. The `register()` method shouldn't have an arrow. Once the arrow gets removed there is no error (store is defined, as well as a router):

```js
    async register() {
      console.log("register()")
      const response = AuthenticationService.register({
        email: 'testss',
        password: 'frgr'
      }).then((response) => {

        console.log(response)
        console.log(this.$store)
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'ha'
        })
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that the `data` property of `response` is not defined.

Is the `AuthenticationService.register` method asynchronous?

I'd imagine it is. If so, your code is continuing before the `response` object has been properly resolved.

Take a second and run `console.log(response)`. You may see an unresolved promise if the method is async.

Otherwise, you may see nothing defined at all if the method does not return anything but instead uses callbacks.

Comment: Okay like I said in my answer, you need to await the promise :) You can use the async/await syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await